# Символ двоеточия в string

Tags: c#, xml, строки, linq2xml

При работе с xml-файлами в C# потребовалось создать через linq2xml такой элемент:

```
xml:space="preserve"
```

Однако при попытке добавить его программно

```
new XAttribute("xml:space", "preserve")
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> "Знак ":", шестнадцатеричное значение
> 0x3A, не может использоваться в
> именах."

Как можно добавить string типа "x:y"?

---

Чуть более полный код:

```
xdoc.Element("root").Add(new XElement("data", new XAttribute("name", x.Key), new XAttribute("xmlspace", "preserve"),new XElement("value", x.Value)));

// Надо xml:space
```

Если кто задается вопросом, "WTF is that?", отвечаю, это программное добавление локализационных ресурсов Visual Studio. (Изначально взято через linq2xml из файла ресурсов Java в Dictionary и потом конвертировано в файл ресурсов Visual Studio), и, да, я знаю толк в извращениях.

Comment: Подозреваю что надо покапать в сторону пространства имён

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А если так:

```
XmlDocument.CreateElement("prefix", "name", "uri"); //для элементов
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"); //для атрибутов
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо.